# formGroup property of FormGroupDirective is not working if bind in normal way

Tags: angular, property-binding

I know how Reactive Forms works in Angular.
We first need to create a FormGroup Object in our TS File and then sync it with our HTML code with help of FormGroupDirective.

Below is the working code :

Sample Typescript Code and HTML Code:

```
export class CarComponent {
  // property that holds object
  myForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormControl('Nancy')
  });

  logOurForm(){
    console.log(this.myForm);
  }
}
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="logOurForm()">
    <input type = "text" [formControlName]="'first'">
    <button type = "submit">Submit Data</button>
</form>
```

Now if we click the button, the form will be logged in to console of browser as expected.

## PROBLEM

The problem occurs, if we use normal syntax to bind to formGroup property of FormGroupDirective.
If we use below code, we get error.

```
<form formGroup [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="logOurForm()">
    <input type = "text" [formControlName]="'first'">
    <button type = "submit">Submit Data</button>
</form>
```

## ERROR: Type string is not assignable to type FormGroup.

### Que 1 : Why do we get this error?

### Que 2 : Why does it work with <form [formGroup]="myForm"> but not with <form formGroup [formGroup]="myForm">?

### Que 3: Why do we see this weird behavior with this directive only? If we try to do same with any other directive, it works perfectly.

Comment: To be able to answer the **Que 3**, can you please provide a reference to the directive for which it works perfectly. Also what are you trying to exactly achieve by repeating `formGroup` multiple times in **Que 2**?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is with the '' in formControlName and the []. Try this.

```
<form formGroup [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="logOurForm()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="first">
    <button type="submit">Submit Data</button>
</form>
```